# how to validate a QuerySelectField in flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask

some one knows a validator in the library wtforms.validators, that can help me to validate that the user can not send the form without select almost one option from the front-end, i try with DataRequired, InputRequired, NoneOf. thanks

Answer (score 0):

after reading the section Custom validators, i could understand how to code my own validator for purpose that i need it, that was to block the '__None' value when the user selects the first choice of this type of form, when you use a blank_test_field, the main problem was that the form.validate_on_submit() did not catch this patten, my code:

```
class DeleteUser(FlaskForm):
    all_users = QuerySelectField(query_factory=query_all_users, 
                                allow_blank=True,  
                                #validators=[NoneOf('__None',message='Campo requerido')],
                                blank_text='Select a user to delete...'
                                )
    def check_selection(self, field):
        if field.data == None:
            raise ValidationError('Se debe seleccionar a un usuario')  `
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to define a validator for your form variable, you can use this rule `validate_your_form_variable_name`.

```py
class DeleteUser(FlaskForm):
    all_users = QuerySelectField(query_factory=query_all_users, 
                                allow_blank=True,  
                                #validators=[NoneOf('__None',message='Campo requerido')],
                                blank_text='Select a user to delete...'
                                )

    def validate_all_users(self, field):
        if field.data == None:
            raise ValidationError('Se debe seleccionar a un usuario')  `
```